# Excel - How can I set up a calculation in 1 cell, based on the text in 1 cell and a number in another?

Tags: excel-formula, sum

I have a text in cell `D2` and a number in `E2`.  If the number in `E2` is less than *10*, I need to divide `E2` by *10* and then times it by a particular value, based on the text in `D2`.  I then need that new number or text in `H2`.

`D2` has a drop down with 7 options.
If `D2` = *"Consultant (+7 Years Experience)"* and `E2` is less than *10* (say 6 for example), I would need to do *34 x (6/10)* and have it calculated into `H2`.

And if `D2` = *Consultant 0-6 Years Experience* and `E2` = *6*, it would be *32 x (6/10)*

Comment: Could you please provide more details on the conditions that define the multiplier?

Comment: D2 has a drop down with 7 options. If D2 = "Consultant (+7 Years Experience)" and E2 = less than 10 (say 6 for example), I would need to do 34 x (6/10) and have it calculated into H2.

Comment: For clarity sake, please add that information (properly indented/formatted) to the question. Thanks!

Comment: And if D2 = Consultant 0-6 Years Experience and E2 = 6, it would be 32 x (6/10)

Comment: Where is the _particular value, based on the text in D2_ stored?  Is it a static value, so lots of checks  such as the one @d1sh4 has answered with or is it stored on a sheet somewhere so the 34, 32, etc can be looked up?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I'd go for:

H2 cell:

```
=IF(E2<10, E2/10, 
  IF(D2 = "Consultant (+7 Years Experience)", 34*E2/10,
    IF(D2 = "VALUE2", CALCULATION,
      *etc. based on the number of options in the dropdown*
```

Please note, you need a number of brackets at the end that corresponds to the number of conditions used. What's going on here is that we have nested conditions roughly equivalent to the following:

```
IF (COND1 TRUE, DO THIS, 
   ELSE IF (COND1 FALSE AND COND2 TRUE, DO THIS,
       *etc.*
```

Here's more documentation on IF: [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2).

Your final condition's *FALSE* value is optional.